# Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade

Tags: 13.10

13.10 upgrade hung in middle of install phase. Eventually turned off computer to see what reboot will do.  Now only reboots to terminal mode in root directory.  What to do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy any files off that may be important to you (it may be easiest to do this using a live CD or USB), then reinstall Ubuntu.

Trying to recover your computer from where it is will take far longer than the 15-30 minutes it will take to reinstall and copy all of your files.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the upgrade.  It should identify a smaller set of changes than it initially discovered.  You will need to run the [server (command line) upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades#Ubuntu_Servers_.28Recommended.29).

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sodu do-release-upgrade
```

Before restarting ensure you have completed any pre-upgrade changes.  Some release require certain packages to be removed before the upgrade.